# ¿Cómo concatenar el resultado de consulta en mysql?

Tags: java, mysql, concatenación

Tengo una tabla en una base de datos y he realizado una consulta para saber el nombre de las columnas entre la posición 2 y 11, pero como estos resultados los estoy utilizando en java para realizar otra consulta más adelante (el valor comprendido entre esas columnas), necesito que el resultado me lo devuelva en una concatenación.

El código sería: "SELECT column_name FROM columns WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA <> 'information_schema' AND table_name = 'data' AND ordinal_position >= 2 AND  ordinal_position <= 11 ORDER BY ordinal_position"

¿Cómo podría hacer para que el resultado me salga concatenado en una misma línea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto debería funcionar:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(column_name SEPARATOR ', ') FROM columns WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA <> 'information_schema' AND table_name = 'data' AND ordinal_position >= 2 AND ordinal_position <= 11 ORDER BY ordinal_position;
```

Comment: Cuando lo ejecuto me dice: #1054 - La columna 'columna_comun' en group statement es desconocida.

Comment: La claúsula `GROUP BY` no es necesaria en este caso.

Comment: ¡Muchas Gracias!

Comment: @nachospiu Gracias. corrijo la respuesta

Comment: @PandaDark Si te ha servido, marca la respuesta como util y correcta por favor :)

Comment: @OdeiAlba, ¡claro! también he votado positivamente, pero no tengo la reputación suficiente como para que el voto sea público.

Comment: De nada @PandaDark, @OdeiAlba!